# How to get parent url from a php iFrame inside of html block

Tags: php, html, url, iframe

I have a php iFrame inside an html page. I have to do it this way because its a 3rd party site. I am trying to call the some url vals with $_GET[] but its not working. Then I figured out its a path problem.

How can I call the url vars from a php iFrame in html?

Thanks

Comment: Are you serving the parent html doc or the iframe doc?

Answer (score 0):

Php is server side, but to manage you frames you need something like javascipt which works on client side. I'm affraid that you mix those two things.

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1281918&page=6

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function refreshIframe(){
    var iframeid = "sessionlog";
     var h = parent.window.getElementById(iframeid).src;
     parent.window.getElementById(iframeid).src = h;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Plus you need code which performs redirect:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
window.location="http://someplace.com";
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: But there MUST be a way to call from an iFrame and get the root URL in the address bar no?